# Showing $\mu_f$ is a measure on the $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{B}$ of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, borel-sets, borel-measures

$\def\R{{\mathbb R}}$
Can I please receive help proving this? Thank you.

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is a complete measure space and $f: X\to \R$ is a measurable function. Let $\mu_f(B) = \mu(f^{-1}(B)).$ Show $\mu_f$ is a measure on the $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{B}$ of Borel subsets of $\R.$ Thus, $f$ induces a Borel measure $\mu_f$ on $\R.$

$\textbf{My work so far.}$ Observe that $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite, $\mu$ is saturated. Moreover, $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra. So, $\mu_f(B) = \mu(f^{-1}(B)).$ Thus, it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}.$ Therefore, $f$ induces a Borel measure $\mu_f$ on $\mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 1):

Lots of unnecessary jargon in your writing.

If $B$ is  Borel set in $\mathbb R$ the $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal M$  so $\mu_f$ is well defined. All you have to do is to verify that $\mu_f(\emptyset)=0$ and $\mu_f(\bigcup B_n)=\sum \mu_f(B_n)$ for any disjoint sequence of Borel sets $(B_n)$. For this just observe that $(f^{-1}(B_n))$ is a disjoint sequence in $\mathcal M$ and use the fact that $\mu$ is a  measure.

Comment: Thank you. We need to verify $\mu_f(\emptyset)$ is zero. Note, $1/\sqrt{x}$ is measurable on $[0,1]$ but the function maps 0 to the $\emptyset.$ Because the measure is complete, and we have a measurable function that is defined a.e. and can fail to be defined on subsets of sets of measure zero. The pre-image of the empty set is the empty set itself, hence measurable. idk if that makes sense